# what is the bonding energy of I2 and I3-?

Tags: bond, energy

I need some information of bonding energy.
I found that the bonding energy of $\ce{I2}$ is $\pu{151 kJ/mol}$ (https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/dimethyl-ether-ch3och3-ethanol-ch3ch2oh-constitutional-isome-chapter-9-problem-90p-solution-9781259631757-exc),
but I have some difficulty in searching the bonding energy of $\ce{I3-}$.

Would you inform me the bonding energy of $\ce{I3-}$? ...or is there any theory related how to guess the bonding energy?

Comment: What is 'bonding energy'? Does that refer to the strength of one I-I bond, or something else?